# QCombobox down arrow image

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

How to change Qcombobox down arrow image?
Right now I'm using this QSS code, but this doesn't work, I can't remove down arrow border.

```
QComboBox
{
    border: 0px;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow
{   
    border: 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image-width: 50px;
    border-image: url(./select-BG.png);
    heidth:50px;
    width:100px;
}
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

this is a pretty late answer but I think that I found the solution somewhere in the Qt-forums.

When setting the border to 0px it seems that the whole style of the combo box arrow gets replaced. So I use `QComboBox::drop-down` to set the border to 0x and then use `QComboBox::down-arrow` to define a custom arrow. The code below shows an additional fix for a strange bug where one cannot change the `color` property of the text correctly.

```
QComboBox {
    color: black;
    font: 14px;
    padding: 1px 0px 1px 3px; /* This (useless) line resolves a bug with the font color */
}

QComboBox:focus {
    color: red;
}

QComboBox::drop-down 
{
    border: 0px; /* This seems to replace the whole arrow of the combo box */
}

/* Define a new custom arrow icon for the combo box */
QComboBox::down-arrow {
    image: url(Resources/DropDownArrow.png);
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
}
```

I hope that someone can use this info and get it work :-)

Comment: How does this Resources/DropDownArrow.png work in association with a .qrc file? @FrozenTarzan

Comment: @AustinWitherow: This is not directly related to how you address resources in a QSS file. Since I don't know how the reference should look like without researching myself I ask you to search for QSS + .qrc files in general :-)

Comment: I was able to easily do this by creating a resource in the qrc file, and linking it like so in the qss file... https://github.com/buzzcoin-project/BUZZ/blob/master/src/qt/res/blackTheme.qss#L26

Answer (score 1):

The arrow is on a button whose style is controlled by the `::drop-down` subcontrol. So, to remove the border you can use:

```
QComboBox::drop-down 
{
    border: 0px;
}
```

Comment: for me this removes the appearance of the entire button. I am guessing because it is overriding whatever image property it had before.