# qcombobox should just show down-arrow but not drop-down button

Tags: css, qt, stylesheet, qcombobox

I have a `QComboBox` for which i should just show the down-arrow icon& hide the drop-down button, i mean border sorrounding the down-arrow icon.
I tried with the following style sheet:

```
QComboBox::drop-down:!editable {border: 0px; subcontrol-origin: padding; subcontrol-position: center right; } ");
```

this hides the down-arrow button too. but i want to show the down-arrow button but not border which surrounds it. Any idea how i can achieve this.?

Ideally it would like the combo box in the following image,
https://www.google.ca/search?q=combo+box+images&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=599&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIgZiz2t7_yAIVghUeCh0nZwva#imgrc=e8dbdN9cVRyr8M%3A

following thread was similar, but i have the same issue as chacham15
[QCombobox down arrow image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484776/qcombobox-down-arrow-image)

I used the following style sheet but it's making the whole button invisible, i want down arrow but not button surrounding it.

```
QComboBox::drop-down 
{
    border: 0px;
}
```

Any ideas how i can achieve this.?

Comment: i also tried customizing QComboBox on Qt stylesheets example, it din't work either.. Does anybody know how exactly qcombobox was laid out on its subcontrols.?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from a friend, so instead of setting the border to 0, try setting drop-down button background to "transparent" & set an image to down-arrow.